# What does "Automatic Receipt" in license mean?

Tags: licensing

I see the following statements in [Arphic Public License](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Arphic_Public_License/):

> 1. Automatic Receipt
>
> Each time you redistribute the Font, the recipient automatically
>   receives a license from the original licensor to copy, distribute or
>   modify the Font subject to these terms and conditions. You may not
>   impose any further restrictions on the recipients' exercise of the
>   rights granted herein. You are not responsible for enforcing
>   compliance by third parties to this License.

English is not my native language. I don't want to mis-interpret it. My understanding is that it describes how the APL license propagates between users. It doesn't imply any ***extra*** physical documents besides the APL license itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  It is clarifying that you can't prevent users who you distribute this font to from receiving this same license you received.  You can't by licensing restrict or impede their usage of the font.  Using the term "automatic receipt" is just indicating this happens automatically not that there is any additional physical documentation.  You don't have to generate or provide the user any additional "receipt" that they have received the license.

Comment: @smwikipedia I can't take credit as the author but it did resonate with me, probably after one coding hell or another.